# I need to get a UIButton to fly into the screen

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton, constraints

I have a UIButton that is located in my screen with constraints. (not centered). I simply need to perform some animation that will start it just outside of the screen, unseen, and let it slide in. one button is sliding from left to right and the other button from right to left. They will need to be able to slide back off the screen as well.

i have tried using button.frame.origin.x = 0 - button and its width. I put that in view did load and it stayed exactly where it was. My plan was to save its original center and then animate to slide in to its original center that i saved. Well none of that is working.

All of my methods have not worked so i just deleted it and i am looking for someone to please show me from scratch how they would go about doing this. Any material about cgpoints, centers, and anything related that i will need to read up on to master this technique will also be very greatly appreciated.

Also please keep everything in swift.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a "tool board" class with sliders and buttons on it. It's logically "attached" to a "tool bar". When you tap a button on the bar, the board animatedly "slides" out.

Adapting my constraints to your needs, here's what I'd do.

(1) Set a width constraint of 0 to not display the button.

```
let myButton = UIButton()
let myConstraint = myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
myConstraint.isActive = true
```

(2) Then, when you wish to move it on the screen, reset the width and animate it:

```
myConstraint.constant = 100
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() }
```

Of course, you need other constraints declared, and this constraint needs to have a wider scope than those. For instance, if you want things to be off-screen it's origin can be CGPoint.zero or whatever, but it's final place is something you define. The key point is (a) change the constraints, trying *not* to replace them, then (b) animate the changes.

Comment: Hey i apologize for the delay. I really appreciate your help but I am somewhat new to swift so i have no idea what you were doing in your code. Instead of having you explain everything in detail and having a long chat i just spent the time to look up what you were doing with constraints and how they work. After messing around with it I think i got the hang of it but i am coming across an animation error. If you would like to help me there I would greatly appreciate it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647445/i-am-trying-to-animate-my-unbutton-with-a-constraint-and-the-animation-is-not-wo

Comment: I'm thinking this is the correct place to answer. (I'm actually still a newbie here.) Maybe I didn't stress it well enough - but you really need to **(1) change your constraints**, and *then* **(2) animate**. I'll post a comment in your new question, but that's a common mistake I've been seeing much of lately. Don't change your constraints inside the animation... change them, and *then* animate.