# i am trying to animate my unbutton with a constraint and the animation is not working

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton, constraints

Can some one please tell me why this is not animating? I feel that the code is all perfect but the animate function is not working. The button is jumping instantly from side to side but like i said it isn't animating...

```
func moveResetButton( constraint : NSLayoutConstraint, isOffScreen : Bool)  {

    if isOffScreen {
        //animate the button onto the screen
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            constraint.constant += 120

        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        //animate the button off of the screen
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            constraint.constant -= 120

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a comment to my answer. Basically, you are changing constraints *inside* the animation. That won't work. You need to (1) change the constraints, and **then** (2) animate the change.

Comment: Hey. Yeah i actually i figured it out and added it just now. I found it on a former question on SO and it was in objective-c. I have no idea how i understood it but it worked. lol Thanks for your efforts though. I hope to hear more from you in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. just need to add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` to the code under the constraint change. worked smoothly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sounds like it was a matter of understanding the sequence of view (and view controller) events that fire.